# Most efficient way of splitting a number into whole and decimal parts

Tags: c, optimization

I am trying to split a double into its whole and fraction parts. My code works, but it is much too slow given that the microcontroller I am using does not have a dedicated multiply instruction in assembly. For instance,

```
temp = ((int)(tacc - temp); // This line takes about 500us
```

However, if I do this,

```
temp = (int)(100*(tacc-temp)); // This takes about 4ms
```

I could speed up the microcontroller, but since I'm trying to stay low power, I am curious if it is possible to do this faster. This is the little piece I'm actually interested in optimizing:

```
    txBuffer[5] = ((int)tacc_y); // Whole part
    txBuffer[6] = (int)(100*(tacc_y-txBuffer[5])); // 2 digits of fraction
```

I remember there is a fast way of multiplying by 10 using shifts, such that:

```
a * 10 = (a << 2 + a) << 1
```

I could probably nest this and get multiplication by 100. Is there any other way?

Comment: I assume that `tacc` and `temp` are `double`?

Comment: That shift trick only works on integers, but you need to multiply in floating point.

Comment: I believe that the shifting trick works only if `temp` is *integer*-type. I don't think it works for `double`, `float`, etc.

Comment: How do the `double` values enter your code?

Comment: Besides, I think you should consult the documentation of the `libc` you used for rounding/truncating decimals. Such as (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding-Functions.html) for `gcc`. Often your compiler comes with such builtin functions.

Comment: Hmmm, yes that would certainly make sense. Also they are referring to 'a' above - I changed the variable name because using temp for everything doesn't make sense. @meaning-matters temp is int, tacc and tacc_y are doubles.

Comment: @phoeagon The shift trick for sure does not work.

Comment: @phoeagon, I could use those functions instead of the (int) cast, but I think my biggest issue is the multiplication to get the fraction part out. I'll go check them out and see how much faster floor() is. What if I modify the exponent bits? Although that probably doesn't work in base 2.

Comment: @phoeagon, floor() is roughly 2 times slower than just using an (int) cast.

Comment: floor() is wrong for negative numbers.

Comment: Do you really need floats to solve your (original) problem? Since micros have no FPUs complex code has to be generated by the compiler (probably using math libraries) which is slow. If you have problems with performance you may look in solving your problem with fixed point (integer based) numbers instead. Floating point is only good if you especially need it's nonlinear accuracy characteristic.

Comment: @Jubatian, yes, I need this particular code to be handled on the micro because there are device-specific numerical adjustments to be done. I have transferred as much math as I could away to the next device, but some stuff I cannot get rid of unfortunately :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the correct answer, which may not be the fastest, is this:

```
double whole = trunc(tacc_y);
double fract = tacc_y - whole;

// first, extract (some of) the data into an int
fract = fract * (1<<11);         // should be just an exponent change
int ifract = (int)trunc(fract);

// next, decimalize it (I think)
ifract = ifract * 1000;          // Assuming integer multiply available
ifract = ifract >> 11;

txBuffer[5] = (int)whole;
txBuffer[6] = ifract
```

If integer multiplication is not OK, then your shift trick should now work.

If the floating-point multiply is too stupid to just edit the exponent quickly, then you *can* do it manually by bit twiddling, but I wouldn't recommend it as a first option. In any case, once you've got as far as bit-twiddling FP numbers you might as well just extract the mantissa, or even do the whole operation manually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It is faster, technically, it just doesn't make numbers yet. What does the (1 << 11) do?

Comment: It generates a number 2^11, which basically moves the decimal point 11 places.

Comment: I've just realized that my code gives 3 decimal places of accuracy, but you only asked for 2.

Comment: Basically, shift operators don't work on FP numbers, but multiplying or dividing by powers of two is the equivalent operation. The actual data bits, in the "mantissa", are unaffected; it just adds or subtracts from the exponent, which ought to be a quick operation.

Comment: Neat! That seem to work, it's about 2x faster than my original code. I was actually confused about the 11 in particular. Why 11?

Comment: You need a number big enough not to lose precision. The choice is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are working with doubles. You could try to take a `double` apart bitwise:

```
double input = 10.64;

int sign = *(int64_t *)&input >> 63;

int exponent = (*(int64_t *)&input >> 52) & 0x7FF;

int64_t fraction = (*(int64_t *)&input) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
fraction |= 0x10000000000000;

int64_t whole = fraction >> (52 + 1023 - exponent);

int64_t digits = ((fraction - (whole << (52 + 1023 - exponent))) * 100) >> (52 + 1023 - exponent);

printf("%lf, %ld.%ld\n", input, whole, digits);
```

Comment: Bitwise extraction will only work if you're absolutely sure that the number is not denormalized, NaN, INF, or anything else broken. In practice, that's probably a fine assumption. It also assumes that your processor uses standard IEEE format numbers, which is worth checking.